# Show Full Tables throughs error

Tags: mysql

I'm using `MySql` as database server.

I'm using this query to fetch only table records from a database.

> SHOW FULL TABLES IN dbName WHERE Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE' ;

And it works fine on some servers but on rest of the servers it troughs error.

### Error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     
server version for the right syntax to use near 
'WHERE Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE'' at line 1
```

Note:-We can do this by using `information_schema.TABLES`.But i doesn't have access on `information_schema.TABLES`.

Comment: did you try without the where condition, just to ensure that you see the structure of the table

Comment: Yes i tried that.When i use `Show Tables IN dbName` it works fine on all servers.But when i used Full key word then it starts showing error message.

Comment: Almost certainly an old mysql version would you be able to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html

"Before MySQL 5.0.1, the output from SHOW TABLES contains a single column of table names. Beginning with MySQL 5.0.1, this statement also lists any views in the database. As of MySQL 5.0.2, the FULL modifier is supported such that SHOW FULL TABLES displays a second output column. Values for the second column are BASE TABLE for a table and VIEW for a view."

Almost certainly you are hitting an old Mysql version in those servers where this query is not working, you may have to modify your query to factor those tables where only one field would be available.

Comment: Yes you are very right.But is there any way to get only tables name on old version mysql servers.

Comment: On old versions you will only get tables there, so if you know that this particular server is old, just run the show tables query

Comment: You mean to say that no views are there.

Comment: Yes, old versions of mysql only returned tables for this command